# Calculating the spectrum of the Fredholm coefficient in the Fredholm equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am solving the Fredholm problem of the second kind, using the given code:

```
psi[x_]=3;
K[x_,s_]=Cos[x - s];
PHI = 
DSolveValue[\[Phi][x] == psi[x] + \[Lambda] Integrate[ K[x,s] \[Phi][s], {s, 0, Pi}], \[Phi], x]
```

This gives a solution, which is dependent on the coefficient $\lambda$. I then want to  plot the solutions for various values of $\lambda$ in order to a notion of its range, and do the following

```
Plot[Table[PHI, {\[Lambda], -1, 4, 0.7}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, Pi/2}]
```

However, the plot is blank. Then I am not sure if this really gives the Range of $\lambda$, since a plot does not really say anything about the range of the coefficient. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: You've mixed up function **relationship** and function **value**. Think about the following: what's the difference between `Sin` and `Sin[x]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

psi[x_] = 3;
K[x_, s_] = Cos[x - s];
```

Either solve for `ϕ[x]` vice `ϕ`

```
PHI = DSolveValue[ϕ[x] == 
    psi[x] + λ Integrate[K[x, s] ϕ[s], {s, 0, Pi}], ϕ[x], x];

Plot[
 Table[
   Callout[PHI, NumberForm[λ, {5, 3}]],
   {λ, -1, 4, 0.7}] // Evaluate,
 {x, 0, Pi/2},
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Or add an argument to `ϕ` in the `Plot`

```
Clear[Phi]

PHI = DSolveValue[ϕ[x] == 
    psi[x] + λ Integrate[K[x, s] ϕ[s], {s, 0, Pi}], ϕ, x];

Plot[
 Table[
   Callout[PHI[x], NumberForm[λ, {5, 3}]],
   {λ, -1, 4, 0.7}] // Evaluate,
 {x, 0, Pi/2},
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob, this is great!