# How to do a Picard iteration on a Volterra equation?

Tags: integral-equations, iteration

I want to approximate the solution of a Volterra integral equation using the Picard method, and plot the approximated solutions. For this I have the equation:

[image: image of equation]

where the functions and coefficients are:

```
λ = 1
psi[x_] = Sin[x];
K[x_, y_] = Cos[x/2 - 3 y];
```

and as initial condition, I use $f(0)=0$.

I want to do 30 Picard iterations to start.

Using a central [Mathematica source](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2016/02/27/exact-and-approximate-solutions-of-the-abel%E2%80%93volterra-equations/)  I find the following code structure to experiment with this problem.

I use `Block` to change the values of the variable `x`, which is related to the position of some particle.

So I use the code:

```
PicardIteration[K[x, y], psi[x], y1, 1, 30] := (y[0] = 0); 
ϕ[y_] := Block[{x, pos}, 
  pos = psi[x] + λ*Integrate[K[x, y] ϕ[y - 1], {y, 0, x}], Assumptions -> (x > 0)]; 
  ϕ[y] = Function @@ List[x, pos]; 
  y[n]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[y1[n] x, {n, 50}]], {x, 0, Pi/2}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, Pi/2}]
```

However, I get no forms of the approximated y[n] and no plots. Though, I get no errors. Is there a better way to do Picard iteration on the Volterra equation?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check your code? It seems there might be  mismatched or missing square brackets. It also looks like you redefine psi within its own definitions, which is unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, I redefined it since I though that was the iteration of the solution.

Comment: Please double check your code. As pointed out by @MarcoB , the brackets don't even match for the moment. `y1[n] x` is also obviously wrong, I don't know if it's a careless mistake or you're just modifying the code blindly, if the latter, think carefully about [the question in this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276069/calculating-the-spectrum-of-the-fredholm-coefficient-in-the-fredholm-equation#comment689543_276069) under your previous post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can realize the iteration using `FixedPointList` together with `FunctionInterpolation`

```
sol = FixedPointList[
  Function[fu,
   FunctionInterpolation[
    Sin[x] + 
     NIntegrate[Cos[x/2 - 3 y] fu[y]  , {y, 0, x} ], {x, 0, 
     Pi/2}]  ]  
  , 0 &,    
  SameTest -> (NIntegrate[(#1[s] - #2[s])^2, {s, 0, Pi/2}] < .001 &)
  ]  
Plot[Through[sol [x]] // Evaluate, {x, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, this is what the same as a Picard iteration, in practice!

Comment: Hope it's what you're looking for!

Comment: Yes, it is similar to a Picard iteration, so this will be sufficient. And in fact, I  learned a new use of  FunctionInterpolation. Thanks

Comment: how can I find the fixed point from this iteration? I tried solving f[x_] := Sin[x]; NSolve[fu == f[x], x], and got x -> ConditionalExpression[
   1. (3.14159 - 1. ArcSin[1. fu] + 
      6.28319 ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]]), 
   ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] 
    Integers]}, {x -> 
  ConditionalExpression[
   1. (ArcSin[1. fu] + 
      6.28319 ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]]), 
   ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers]

Comment: `sol[[-1]][x]`should be the fixpoint!

Comment: Great, thanks. I note that a fixed "point" for the Volterra problem is not a point, but a continuous function, which results from your command. Thanks